# Saving users answer onsubmit to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a project in school. This project is about creating a web-form where the user can choose an activity and then proceed to fill out their personal information. This information then has to be printed on an Admin page where you should be able to see all information regarding that specific person under the given activity, depending on what they chose.

What I'm struggeling with is how I get the activity that they've chosen with the `<select>` `<option>` tag to appear in local.storage. Since I don't know what they're gonna pick.

I've created a function onsubmit named `sportVal()`. Shouldn't i be able to get the information by having something like this in my JS?:

```js
function sportVal() {
  var sportVal = document.getElementById("sportList").value;
  localStorage.setItem("sportList");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="sportVal()" name="frmDataEntry" action="Uppgifter.html" method="POST">
  <select id="sportList">
        <option id="Tennis" value="Tennis">Tennis</option> 
        <option id="Fotboll" value="Fotboll">Fotboll</option> 
     </select>
  </br>
  <input id="Knapp" type="submit" value="Gå vidare >>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a misstake on the post-side of things. It's supposed to be setItem. Still, is it possible to get the value of the user choice with setItem?

Comment: Well, since you already set it, you should be able to get it later on using `getItem`

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem). You need a key _and_ a value for `setItem`: `.setItem("sportList", sportVal)`.

Comment: Sure! Though get 0 results in Inspect --> Application

Comment: It’s not recommended to use a variable with the same name as the function it’s inside of. Also there is no `</br>`; it’s supposed to be `<br/>`.

Comment: Do you mean, what another user chose, you want to see in your admin page? This seems like typical information that you would save server side. Will all the users be filling this form out on 1 computer?

Comment: The Admin page is just another HTML page where I am to list all the people and what activity they choose. From my little understanding regarding this I'm to save the user generated choice and information in localstorage and then print it out on the other page with getItem. Or am I totally off?

Comment: Well, `localStorage` is a place on the clients pc to save data to, so if 3 people navigate from their own laptop to your website, all of them will have an empty `localStorage` to start with, and saving the changes on their local machine won't make it visible for you on your server (as your `localStorage` would only contain your own choice). Do you have any server side language you could use?

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on this. As I said I'm very new to this. Where should I look if I need to learn how to get the user choice and input values on said "Admin-page" with just JS and HTML? That would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using localStorage.getItem("sportList") you are trying to return the value of a item called 'sportList' that is already in your storage.
To save something in localStorage you should use:

```
localStorage.setItem('nameOfItem', itemValue);
```

In you case you can get and save the element like this

```
var e = document.getElementById("sportList").value;
localStorage.setItem('selectedItem', e);
```

Just remember if you need to save an object, you will have probably to stringfy it.

```
JSON.stringfy(yourObject)
```

According to Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

> "The setItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name
>   and value, will add that key to the storage, or update that key's
>   value if it already exists."

> The getItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name,
>   will return that key's value.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.the first problem with your code is that your function declaration is not actually passing the value you which to store to the localstorage.

```
function sportVal() {
  var sportVal = document.getElementById("sportList").value;
  localStorage.setItem("sportList",sportVal);
  //get value of from local storage
  var result=localStorage.getItem("sportList")
  alert(result);
}
```